# iOS Project Huge Folder Size

Tags: ios, project

I'm working on an iOS app which I just went to zip up - for some reason the zip is 1+GB :p

I checked all the contents and there;s nothing more than 100MB. So why such a larger folder size - is there a standard way to clean up any unused bits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls -a` to see any hidden files in you folder.

Comment: Ah yes. Found a .git folder - I presume its safe to delete this as I'm keeping a local copy only?

Comment: That's your git repository. If you're not using git you can get rid of it. You *should* however be using some sort of source control, even for small, one-man projects.

Comment: Do you use any source control system like bitbucket.org, you can push you code and pull again, and then you can zip the clean code. I don't think there is a problem even you delete .git folder. But you will miss all you local commit history.

Comment: I use the the version control provided by x-code. I use ls -a and I found a .git file and a .DS_Store file. They are hidden and How can I show them and delete them?

Comment: You can delete them using `rm -rf .git`, but you will lost all git local history if you don't pull them before you delete them.